# iframe that grows to specified size

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to set up an image that, when clicked, opens an iframe that gradually gets bigger, then closes onmouseout. Here is what I have so far:

```
<html>  
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function makeFrame(src) {
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src","");
ifrm.setAttribute("onmouseout","closeFrame()")
ifrm.setAttribute("onclick","grow()")
ifrm.setAttribute("id","amazingIFrame")
ifrm.style.display = "block";
ifrm.style.width = 640+"px";
ifrm.style.height = 400+"px";
ifrm.style.marginLeft = "325";
ifrm.style.marginTop = "125";
ifrm.style.position = "absolute";
ifrm.style.top="0px";
ifrm.style.color="red";
ifrm.style.zIndex= "101";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
function closeFrame(){
ifrm.style.display = "none";
}
function grow() {
    ifrm = document.getElementById('amazingIFrame');
    if (ifrm.style.width < 500) {
        ifrm.style.width += 10;
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);  // stop growing when it's big enough
    }
}
function startGrow() {
    interval = setInterval("grow()", 10);  // repeat every 10 ms
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<img src="" onclick="makeFrame()" "height="100px" width="100px" />

</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work, though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues.

- you never call `startGrow()`.
- the iframe is already sized above 500px when you create it
- ifrm.style.width < 500 is not right. ifrm.style.width will include the px, so you'll be comparing 10px with 500...
- the setInterval syntax is incorrect. Should be setInterval(grow, 10);
- height has a double quote before it
- you're not passing any parameters, so src is going to be null (really just unnecessary).

Try like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mb7DU/4/)

```
function makeFrame() {
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src","");
ifrm.setAttribute("onmouseout","closeFrame()")
ifrm.setAttribute("onclick","grow()")
ifrm.setAttribute("id","amazingIFrame")
ifrm.style.display = "block";
ifrm.style.width = 0;
ifrm.style.height = 400+"px";
ifrm.style.marginLeft = "325";
ifrm.style.marginTop = "125";
ifrm.style.position = "absolute";
ifrm.style.top="0px";
ifrm.style.color="red";
ifrm.style.zIndex= "101";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
startGrow();
}
function closeFrame(){
ifrm.style.display = "none";
}
function grow() {
    ifrm = document.getElementById('amazingIFrame');
    var width = parseInt(ifrm.style.width.replace("px",""));
    if (width < 500) {
        ifrm.style.width = (width + 10) +"px";
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);  // stop growing when it's big enough
    }
}
function startGrow() {
    interval = setInterval(grow, 10);  // repeat every 10 ms
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The click event you are hooking up will only fire if you click on the iframe. Give it a wide border, click on the border and you'll find it works. Put an alert after `ifrm = document.getElementById('amazingIFrame');`, and you'll see.

If you want to make it so that the click event fires when you click inside the iframe, you'll have to put some HTML in there and hook up and event to the DOM that is in the Iframe itself.